# Okta SAML login is not success

Tags: java, saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta, okta-api

Implementing SAML using Okta as the IdP. The log-in is working fine when the project is running in my local machine and in our QA machine. The same project doesn't work when I move it to production. I am giving the DNS name in the place of a URL and the production instance is HTTPS. When I tried it's showing an error about end points not matching. I copied the IdP metadata contents in to the `idp.xml` file in my project.  Using Spring Security SAML. I followed the instructions in: http://developer.okta.com/code/java/spring_security_saml.html

What is wrong here? Am I missing anything?

***UPDATED***

Error : -

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Incoming SAML message is invalid
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)


Caused by: org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException: SAML message intended destination endpoint did not match recipient endpoint
at org.opensaml.common.binding.decoding.BaseSAMLMessageDecoder.checkEndpointURI(BaseSAMLMessageDecoder.java:217)
at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:72)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

check your SP metadata (the metadata you generate) and ensure the endpoints it references reflects the production DNS setup

Comment: Hi martin thanks for the reply, actually am able to login when my application is http but for https its showing error. What change i need to make so that my application will work ?

Comment: Make sure that HTTPS is configured correctly and is using properly signed certificates. 

For your production instance, make sure that the HTTPS certificate is signed by a [certificate authority that is trusted by Java](http://superuser.com/questions/55470/which-trusted-root-certificates-are-included-in-java), Spring Security SAML might be running into an TLS error when fetching the SAML metadata from your SAML SP.

Comment: @JoëlFranusic hi Joel, we are using amazon servers, and its configured correctly, Do we need to make any particular changes in okta and in my application for https?? Do you have any reference?

Comment: Can you please edit your question above with more detailed error messages?